# How to know the container ID, process ID and task ID in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel

In case of multiple container environment, how to know which the system calls (Read/Write/Open/Close) triggered from which container.

Every system call arrived at vfs layer with appropriate file structure and redirected to the corresponding file operation which ever assigned.

From this VFS layer i want to know which container triggered this system call from the user space and also want to know process ID and task ID of the container

Comment: can you add detail on which container technology you're specifically referring to? I could see that in a highly-isolated virtualization environment, at least container ID might be something you shouldn't be able to figure out at all.

Comment: I need the solution on linux container